# jQuery selector not working in script but works in console

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

this is a very odd problem indeed and I hope it's simple. I cannot get a simple select and append to work in my html document, but it works when I'm in the chrome browser console.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js" integrity="sha256-aaODHAgvwQW1bFOGXMeX+pC4PZIPsvn2h1sArYOhgXQ="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="/js/script.js"></script>
<script>
$('[data-js="works"]').append("hello");
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div data-js="works"></div>
test

</body>
</html>
```

When I put that line of script in the console, hello appears above test. When I just open the page, test is there alone. I was running a script from this page earlier and when I tried to select an element it didn't work. I then went to inline script to see if it would even work there, no. I've seen if it works from inline script without the imported script, also no. Console has no bug information. I can print from that inline script to my console if I want, but this code still isn't running properly.

Doesn't work with my local httpserver and doesn't work just as a locally opened file.

Comment: You're running your JS before the actual elements exist on the page. Put your script before the closing body tag or wrap it in a document ready call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the script is executed before the page is loaded so the target div does not exist yet.

The solution is to wait for the page to be fully loaded before doing something.
The `$` function can be used for this. Give it a callback and it will be executed once the page is loaded.

You can also use `window.addEventListener("load", callback);` that doesn't need `jQuery`.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js" integrity="sha256-aaODHAgvwQW1bFOGXMeX+pC4PZIPsvn2h1sArYOhgXQ="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
      $(function(){
        $('[data-js=works]').append("hello");
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div data-js="works"></div>
    test

  </body>
</html>
```

Another solution can be to insert your script at the end of the page. It is not as neat though in my opinion.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js" integrity="sha256-aaODHAgvwQW1bFOGXMeX+pC4PZIPsvn2h1sArYOhgXQ="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div data-js="works"></div>
    test

    <script>
      $('[data-js=works]').append("hello");
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, hope it will solve your problem

```
(function($) {  // This will solve namespace problem (if any)
    // Write your JQuery code here
})(jQuery);
```

Either you put the .js file at the end of the body or put your JS code between `$(document).ready(function(){ //code inside  })`